# Navigation Bar size staying relative to content

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am having some trouble with the navigation bar for my website. I have created the nav bar using lists and CSS styling. The clickable boxes that are on the bar stay small and relative to the size of the contents within that box but I want it to be a set size.

```
#navbar ul, #navbar ul li {padding:0; margin:0; list-style:none; }
#navbar a{color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold;}
#navbar a:hover{background:#777777;}
#navbar li a:link, #navbar li a:visited {background:#444444; text-decoration:none; height:24px; line-height:24px; display:inline; float:left; width:auto; padding:0px 10px;}
```

This is the CSS that I am using for the nav bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting:

```
 display:block;
```

on your anchor tag, combined with some padding to bring the styling away from the text?

Comment: I have:
#navbar{width:auto; display:block; height:24px;}

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the problem, is each navbar element only the width/height of the text?  Usually setting a width/height on the anchor tag combined with display:block; on it itself would sort that. 

At the moment you're setting the anchor tag to display:inline; for visited links with this line:

#navbar li a:visited {background:#444444; text-decoration:none; height:24px; line-height:24px; display:inline; float:left; width:auto; padding:0px 10px;}

Comment: I think you can see the problem. I have everything set out right but its just not working. Each navbar element is the width/height of the text. I will quickly try setting a fixed width on the anchor tag.
Edit: Ah I see. will have a play now

Comment: Sure thing. Ensuring display:block; is set on the a's should fix that. As for fixed with, you could do it using padding to create equal space around the text of each element without forcing them to occupy the same space regardless of text length. // Nevermind, see you were doing that alongside a fixed height. In which case hopefully explicitly setting them as blocks should help.

Comment: Im sorry to be a pain but I didn't understand your last post. Thanks for the replies though!

Comment: Weird, I just did a test in jsFiddle and it appears as thought I was wrong about display:block; (one has it one doesn't) http://jsfiddle.net/6K5vu/1/ in which case I don't have much else to offer I'm afraid. Sorry about that, I hope you get it fixed.

I'm almost positive you will have, but the only thing that comes ot mind is if you don't have float:left; set on your normal a (not :visited etc) tags as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/6K5vu/2/

Comment: The problem is solved. Within the #navbar li a:link, `#navbar li a:visited` the width was set to auto, so I changed that to my desired width. Was my bad creating it in the first place. Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted in the end!